# CSS or jQuery problem: Website not behaving correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Go to this beta of my new website `(link redacted)`. If you hover over one of the colored squares, a popup box à la Panic's Coda pops up, except there are two problems:

a) The text inside the popup does not show up. It is programmatically set to `:)` using the following code:

[http://grab.by/syM http://grab.by/syM](http://grab.by/syM)

```
$('td.middle', this).text(':)');
```

`td.middle` is the class of the middle cell
     `this` is a reference to `$('.info').each()`

Use may want to use an inspector tool like Firebug for Firefox or the one included one in Safari or Google Chrome.

b) The sides are clipped off:

[http://grab.by/syE http://grab.by/syE](http://grab.by/syE)

I think it is due to this:
[http://grab.by/syW http://grab.by/syW](http://grab.by/syW)

For some reason, the sides have computed `width`s of 1px, as opposed to

```
.bubbleInfo .popup td.corner {
 position: inherit;
 height: 15px;
 width: 19px;
}
```

19px as defined in  `(link redacted)`

---

You can grab a ZIP archive of all the files here  `(link redacted)`.

Thanks so much. I know this is a lot to ask.

Comment: In FireFox, I see the :) inside your popup.  It's off center (basically it's left) but it's in there.

Comment: That's interesting. I see that, too (looking in Firefox). I'll add a `text-align: center` after, but I guess that doesn't solve why it doesn't show up in Safari or why the sides are clipped. Looking at it in Chrome, the text doesn't show up. I wonder what makes it display differently in Firefox.

Comment: If Firefox, I see the same thing Frank does. In IE8, the nonexistent popups are the *least* of your worries - to begin with, only the rightmost colored boxes show up (the orange/yellow ones), and the page gives a script error. (Object doesn't support this property or method, jquery.classes.js line 1 Char 311.)

Comment: Just checked Opera - no errors and the colored boxes are all there, but the popups are empty.

Comment: Okay. I just updated the files to keep the line breaks so we can see exactly where Martha is getting her IE8 problem.

Comment: IE 6 and 7 both throw errors on line 20, char 1, the usual Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: Wow does it look different in Chrome - the background with the rounded corners shows up, I was totally shocked.  No smilies in the popups, though. :(

Comment: @Frank DeRosa:  
It's okay that they throw errors. IE isn't anyone's browser of choice. We'll have some sort of intervention for IE users. What did you mean about being shocked about the background?

Comment: I was shocked because it was suddenly there!  I didn't see the background in FF or IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of the container div for the :) table is clipping the sides of the :) table popup.  If you edit the width of the .info class up from 32 to something bigger (I did `width:80px`) you see the whole popup.  Alternately, you can change the width (or min-width) of .popup to about 50px, which fixes them without distorting the size of the colored boxes.

As for the :) being missing, I was able to make it appear by setting `text-indent:0` in the .middle class.  This had no ill effects on FireFox and fixed it in Chrome.

Comment: But we still can't figure out why the `:)` text only shows up in Firefox.

Comment: I found the minimum width for seeing the whole popup to be 50px.  I tried setting overflow on .info, but it wasn't helpful.  If I set the .popup class to a width of 50px that works as well, though you'll need to adjust margins or something else to get the popup centered again.

Comment: But why does the `:)` only show up in Firefox? Any ideas? This is the hard part.

Comment: See my revised answer above - I got it (at least in Chrome and Safari) to show your :)

Comment: Ooooh! I just figured out the problem. I put some text into the colored boxes to show up if the background images couldn't be found, and I added a large, negative `text-indent`. You have to add a `text-indent: 0` in order to cancel it out. I wonder why the width is funky like that, but it's easily fixed. I'll probably just use jQuery to set all of the `.popup` widths. Thanks so much.